# Dealing with 130 currencies for products MySQL

Tags: mysql

Currently we have a database that stores many products but only in a few currencies. This has meant storing the price with the product entry and it works well enough.

We are about to open things up though and allow 130+ currencies. As we allow a product to be sold in multiple currencies (of the clients choice) this produces a problem with the current setup.

What I am proposing is a table that comprises of the product id and each currency, so a look up table for price. Of course only the relevant currencies will be selected when in operation.

Although this will keep the main product table uncongested it still seems a bit unwieldy especially as many of the currencies will be very limited in use.

In would be good to have a number of tables to break things up a bit but then I don't know how a `JOIN` would occur, as far as I know you can't get a value from table A and work out which table to `JOIN` with based on that value(s).

Or maybe 130 columns just isn't something to worry about?

Comment: How do you calculate the price in a given currency? If you've got a calculation that's used for that, then I'd think you'd want to store all prices in the base currency, and then have a table with the conversion rates for each currency. If prices in each currency are manually tweaked, obviously that won't work.

Comment: No they are manually set unfortunately.

Comment: Have you considered a table with the columns `product_id`, `currency_code`, `value`?

Comment: No but that could be a good idea, then I could group the results for multi-currency products. Probably the way to go actually. One disadvantage is that this will add more data to the table, I'm not sure what the performance trade off would be like.

Comment: No, the original table shrinks.  The new table will be somewhat bulky, but that should not be a big worry.  But do have `PRIMARY KEY(product_id, currency_code)`.